# How to add youtube frame to ERB file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube

I have url of video in post.url

How can I add youtube frame?

I used this

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src= <%= \" post.url \"%>  

    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>

</iframe> 

<% end %>
```

And get this error

> syntax error, unexpected $undefined ...reeze;
>   @output_buffer.append=( \" post.url \");

Also I Used

```
 src= <%= post.url %>
```

And I didn't see anything

Comment: you should read and follow https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: Try this `<% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <iframe src=#{post.url} frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
    <% end %>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer not to mix ERB tags with HTML tags, therefore I would suggest using the `content_tag` helper method instead:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= content_tag(:iframe, '', src: post.url, 
                   width: 560, height: 315, frameborder: 0) %>
<% end %>
```

**Or even better:** define a helper method in e.g. `helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
def youtube_frame(url)
  content_tag(:iframe, '', src: url, width: 560, height: 315, frameborder: 0)     
end
```

and use that method in your view to make the code more readable and easier to understand:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= youtube_frame(post.url) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the quotes around erb tag:

```
src="<%= post.url %>"
```

So your code will be:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<%= post.url %>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 

<% end %>
```